# Can we have while loop test two arguments at the same time without &&/||

Tags: c, ipc

I was checking Beej's guide to [IPC](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/fifos.html) and one line of code took my attention.

In the particular page, the while loop in `speak.c` has two conditions to check `while (gets(s), !feof(stdin))`.

So my question is how is this possible as I have seen while look testing only one condition most of the time.

PS: I am little new to these. Will be grateful for any help. Thanks!

Comment: If you find a book/guide written after 1990 that uses `gets` whatsoever, you should burn it. The author is incompetent and you will pick up very bad habits from reading their examples...

Comment: @R.. Beej's guide is a f@#king atrocity and should be scrubbed from the interwebs, and the quoted code should be exhibit A in his capital trial in the Hague.

Comment: Wow, it's really that bad....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The snippet

```
while (gets(s), !feof(stdin))
```

uses the *comma operator*, first it executes `gets(s)`, then it tests `!feof(stdin)`, which is the result of the condition.

By the way **don't use gets**, it's extremely unsafe. Be wary of sources using it, they probably aren't good sources for learning the language.

The code

```
while(gets(s), !feof(stdin)) {
    /* loop body */
}
```

is equivalent to

```
gets(s);
while(!feof(stdin)) {
    /* loop body */
    gets(s);
}
```

just more concise as it avoids the repetition of `gets` before the loop and in the loop body.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of people have already pointed out some of the problems with this. I certainly agree that using `gets` (at all) is a lousy idea.

I think it's worth mentioning one other detail though: since this uses `feof(file)` as the condition for exiting the loop, it can/will also misbehave if you encounter an error before the end of the file. When an error occurs, the error flag will be set but (normally) the EOF flag won't be -- and since you can't read from the file any more (due to the error) it never will be either, so this will go into an infinite loop.

The right way to do the job is with `fgets`, and check its return value:

```
while (fgets(s, length_of_s, stdin))
    process(s);
```

This tests for `fgets` *succeeding* at reading from the file, so it'll exit the loop for either end of file *or* an error.

One other minor detail: when `fgets` reads a string, it normally *retains* the new-line at the end of the line (where `gets` throws it away). You'll probably have to add a little more code to strip it off is it's present (and possibly deal with a line longer than the buffer you allocated if the newline isn't present).

Comment: Note that the original version of the code would throw away the last line of the file if it did not end in a newline.

Answer (score 2):

This test is using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) and has been used as a way of getting the next line of text using `gets(s)` and testing for end-of-file using `!feof(stdin)`.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax doesn't evaluate two expression. It executes first the `gets(s)` and then evaluates `!feof(stdin)` which may be modified by the `gets()` function call.

It's not a very good way to do it since it both use `gets()`, which is not a safe function and it's quite uneasy to read for a beginner (hence your question).